# Why do some pairs of Tzitzit have one hole on each corner and some have two?

Tags: number, tzitzis

There are Tzitzit that have one hole and some have two. What is the significance of the multiple holes? Whose custom is it to have one? Whose custom is it to have two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Beis Yosef, in the [last paragraph in Orach Chaim chapter 11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&st=&pgnum=42&hilite=), deals with this issue.  The reason for 2 holes seems to be that when you put the tzitzis through 1 hole, they apply on both sides of the garment, making them 8 and not 4 and therefore pasul (reason?).

Based on the minhag around the Beis Yosef, he did not subscribe to this logic and said that wearing 2-hole tzitzis would be arrogant.  Others give much weight to the 2-hole theory.  Mishna Berurah, Chapter 11, paragraph 9(39), cites the Beis Yosef and others.  The Mishna Berurah gives power to both minhagim that have developed, and concludes that each person should follow his community's custom.  See the Mishna Berurah inside; an [English translation](https://web.archive.org/web/20120526113338/http://torah.org/advanced/mishna-berura/S11.html) is available online.

Comment: what is the svara (i don't understand it) based on only having one hole used [when 2 are actuly there??} why not 4 holes, or 5 or 7, etc, ??
either way, even if you put it through both holes, wouldn't the strings still appear on both sides (albeit on one side, just for a small section??)
please explain the svara?
and wasn't the gra a mekubal as well?
[perhaps his shita was based on svara, or perhaps.......

Comment: with 2 holes, you don't have to fold the tzizit in half.

Comment: @mechoel zev, could you please rephrase your question?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen followers of *minhagei haGr"a* having two holes in each corner of the *talis katan*.

This practice is also listed in the *Sefer Haminhagim* of Chaba"d.

Comment: Gra-Chabad customs are generally the city custom of Jerusalem, as I understand. Is having two-holed corners a J-m custom?

Comment: IS there a stated reason?

Comment: I've never heard of this being among Minhagei HaGR"A.  But that could be.  It's definitely practiced widely by ChaBa"D.

Comment: @msh210 - What is J-m?

Comment: @ezra, Jerusalem, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The AriZal says in Shaar HaKawanot Derush Waw that there should be 2 holes on the Tallit Katan and 1 on the Tallit Gadol (based on the Agor, and in Peri Es Haim Shaar Sisit Pereq Alef he quotes the Itur). According to most Posekim there should be one in each.

Comment: Hi Gabi Hanson and welcome to Judaism.SE! Can you cite the _Itur_ specifically? I look forward to seeing you and your additions around.