# Tzitzit: Do they hang straight down from the corner or do they hang from the side, past the corner?

Tags: clothing, tzitzis

Wearing Tzitzit:  They are attached on a corner.  Do they proceed laterally to the edge and then down?  Or do they proceed directly down?  I am pretty sure they do not proceed to the corner (mathematically speaking).

Comment: @msh210: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18316/603

Answer (score 2):

To the lateral edge (the  side)  and then down.  Magen Avraham sk 24 added in name of the Levush that diagonal is the worst solution because it can lead to believe that the corner need 2tsitsiot (on each edge)

See [SA OC 11,  15](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x363):

> יש אומרים שצריך לדקדק שיתלה הציציות **לאורך הטלית דבעינן שתהא נוטפת על הקרן** (פירוש, תלוי על הקרן) ואם היה ברחבו לא היה נוטף שהרי כלפי קרקע היה תלוי יש אומרים שאין לתת שום בגד בנקבי הטלית שמכניסים בה הציציות ויש מתירין וכן נהגו:
>
> From the lateral edge the Tzitzis down along this edge  and go out from the inferior edge exactly at the corner.