# Why are the holes diagonal on a Chabad tallis katan?

Tags: tzitzis, chabad, tallit-katan

So I understand the reasoning for having two holes on the tallis katan (so that the tzitzis will hang on one side of the corner and won't move around), but why do Chabad tallis katans have the holes at a diagonal? Other Chassidic tallis katans just have two horizontal holes.

[image: Chabad tallis katan]

Photo courtesy of [Ben's Tallit Shop](http://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/chabad-tallis-katan/).

Comment: Never knew this. I guess you're Chabad? Do you have a pic that you can upload or link to? This is only on the TK and not the TG?

Comment: @DanF - Affiliated with Chabad; I try to follow all of the Chabad minhagim. I hope one day I can call myself a chosid! I do wear a Chabad tallis katan, though.

Comment: @DanF - The diagonal holes are on the tallis katan only. The tallis gadol also has two holes, but they are placed a bit differently: [Chabad Tallis Gadol](http://www.tallit-shop.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Mishkan-Chabad-tzitzit1.jpg)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76353/9215

Comment: @ezra The 2 holes in the tallit katan are part of the mitzvah. After reviewing this over Shabbat, it seems to be a consequence of the language used in the She’iltot d’Rav Achai Gaon to Sefer Devarim. The 2nd hole in the tallit gadol, a recommendation of the Alter Rebbe in Seder Tefillot miKol HaShanah, is only something used to prevent the tzitzit from hanging down below the place they are supposed to be.

Comment: @YaacovDeane The two holes cannot be part of the mitzvah according to kulei alma, because not everyone agrees to have two holes on the tallis katan. It's even dubious the Arizal himself had two holes on his, even though the custom is erroneously attributed to him.

Comment: @ezra You should look over Sifri, Ramban and Kli Yakar to Devarim 2:12. The key to understanding this seems to be understanding the meaning of the word כנפות used here. According to Rav Achai Gaon it is to be understood as קרן זוית which means corner, not border. Therefore, the orientation of the Tzerei formed by the 2 holes in the tallit katan needs to be perpendicular to the corner, not the bordering edge, of the garment.

Comment: @ezra Regarding your mistaken understanding of the two holes, see the actual source in Itur Sofrim quoted in the link from kouty in the comments above. Ba’al HaItur clearly connects this to the teachings of the Gaonim.

Comment: @ezra The tallit katan cannot be used by an adult to fulfill the mitzvah of tzitzit except in pressing circumstances. Its function, as used by Chabad, is to allow the individual to fulfill all opinions about the mitzvah of tzitzit. The tallit gadol used by Chabad is according to the majority opinion in Shulchan Aruch with the possible exception of the ‘holding hole’ recommended by the Alter Rebbe.

Comment: @ezra it is not, as you say “dubious”, meaning doubtful and suspect of being untrue, that the Ari z”l wore his tallit katan with 2 holes on each corner as done by Chabad. Unless you consider the written testimony of his primary student, Rabbi Chaim Vital to be dubious. He writes in Sha’ar HaKavannot, Inyan HaTzitzit, Drush 6, that he was an eye witness to the Ari wearing his tallit katan in exactly this fashion as found in Sefer HaItur. He also states that this was only done by the Ari with his tallit katan and not with his tallit gadol.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why Chabad follow this practice is because the Rebbe wrote about it specifically in his [Igrot Kodesh, Volume 2, pg. 313, letter 342](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15907&st=&pgnum=339) saying it was the practice of his father-in-law, the previous Rebbe, Rabbi Yosef Yitzchok Schneersohn.

Comment: And why was it his father's practice?

Comment: @DoubleAA ironic you ask this about the Rayatz given the maaseh listed here about Modeh Ani: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/42749/jewish/A-Rebbes-Education.htm (4th story down)