# Origin of diagonal holes for tzitzit

Tags: sources-mekorot, tallit-katan

The Chabad practice is to make diagonal holes for the tzitzit in a tallit katan

[image: Chabad tallis katan] (from [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85245/why-are-the-holes-diagonal-on-a-chabad-tallis-katan)).

The Lubavitcher Rebbe wrote in his [Igrot Kodesh](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15907&st=&pgnum=339) saying it was the practice of his father-in-law. On the other side the Hazon Ish (printed in the back of the Mishnah Berurah) says in his opinion the practice is forbidden.

So what is the rationale and origin of this practice?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85245/why-are-the-holes-diagonal-on-a-chabad-tallis-katan

Comment: @mbloch I've never quite figured out how to put images into questions. In this case, your link to the  related question accomplishes the task. The Chain Ish comment  is printed in the back of the Mishnah Berurah. He doesn't comment on the source for the practice. Only his thoughts for prohibiting it.

Comment: How is this not a dupe of my question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85245/why-are-the-holes-diagonal-on-a-chabad-tallis-katan)?

Comment: @ezra Your question is specifically why Chabad does it. That has been answered. But it doesn't address what the source for diagonal holes is, in general. Particularly when the comments of the Chazon Ish are considered, it begs clarification.

Comment: See here an answer https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76353/9215

Comment: [Rabbi LY Raskin](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&st=&pgnum=76) says he couldn't either find a source for this (beyond the *Siddur HaRav*).

Comment: Clarification, please, based on the picture. The holes themselves look circular. I think on many *tallitot katan* (I **think** that's the correct plural?) the holes are more square. I assume that you mean that the holes are **placed** diagonally?  Incidentally, there are 2 holes next to each other. That's also unusual, though you're not questioning that. Would you know the reason for having two holes?

Comment: @DanF The subject of 2 holes or 1 is dealt with in the linked answer from Kouty above in the comments. To my knowledge, there is no concept about the shape of the holes, only that there be holes. Diagonal means here that the Tzerei formed by the holes is not parallel to either the side or bottom edge of the garment. It is perpendicular to the bisect of the right angle formed from the garment’s corners.

Comment: Since the practice is purported to be attributed to the Ari z"l, I'm wondering if there may be some hint to it's origin in Sefer Divrei Shalom to Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim.

Comment: @YaacovDeane The practice of having 2 holes bichlal is attributed to the Arizal, although even that is dubious. As for the 2 holes being diagonal, we're still at a loss for a source. I even checked the Piskei HaSiddur and couldn't find anything there, although the Sefer Haminhagim references it.

Comment: @ezra The Ba'al HaItur is long before the Ari and he clearly mentions two holes being used at each corner when hanging the tzitzit. He says that one end of the four threads goes through one hole and the other end of the four threads goes through the other hole. So at the very least, the earliest source mentioning two holes at each corner is the author of the Itur Sofrim, not the Ari z"l. But he seems to be saying his practice comes from Rabbi Yehudai HaKohen Gaon. That is likely where the earliest source is.